# Error on Notistack after update Material UI to version Alpha 6

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, notistack

I need a feature from Material UI 6, which is variant, and I to get that feature I have update my dependencies and fixed all breaking changes, but now I receive this error:

```js
index.js:1 Warning: Unknown event handler property `onEnter`. It will be ignored.
    in div (created by ClickAwayListener)
    in ClickAwayListener (created by ForwardRef(Snackbar))
    in ForwardRef(Snackbar) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Snackbar)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Snackbar)) (created by SnackbarItem)
    in div (created by Transition)
    in div (created by Transition)
    in div (created by Transition)
    in Transition (created by ForwardRef(Collapse))
    in ForwardRef(Collapse) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Collapse)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Collapse)) (created by SnackbarItem)
    in SnackbarItem (created by WithStyles(SnackbarItem))
    in WithStyles(SnackbarItem) (created by SnackbarProvider)
    in div (created by SnackbarContainer)
    in SnackbarContainer (created by SnackbarProvider)
    in SnackbarProvider (at src/index.js:56)
    in ThemeProvider (at src/index.js:55)
```

When something from Notistack is showed at the interface, is there a way to fix the problem related to the event `onEnter`? I have read a few threads but nothing relates to the environment that I have...

Obs: The alert don't disappear after the duration time specified